# How can I simulate a lost connection with java/selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

We're using Selenium 2 with Java in our test automation process.
Our web application periodically polls for new information - if it can't connect to the server (ie. server down, cable unplugged, ...), a popup should appear.

Is there any (easy) way to simulate a lost connection in Java or directly in Selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. I'm using [Vaurien](http://vaurien.readthedocs.org/en/1.8/), the chaos TCP proxy to simulate network problems.

According to the documentation, an example to add 20% delay of all HTTP requests:

```
vaurien --protocol http --proxy localhost:8000 --backend google.com:80 --behavior 20:delay
```

You can find all "behaviors" here: http://vaurien.readthedocs.org/en/1.8/behaviors.html
In my opinion, `hang` behavior can be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks! I have heard of Netflix' Chaos Monkey before, but Vaurien is new to me - looks very promising.